# In Java, can a class access the protected attribute in the super class of its super class?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, protected

For example,

```
public class Question {
protected String question, correctAnswer, type;
....

}

public class MultipleChoice extends Question{{
  ...
}

public class TrueFalse extends MultipleChoice{
public TrueFalse(){
    this.type = "TrueFalse";
    this.question = "Question is not assinged!";
    this.correctAnswer = "Correct Answer is not assinged!";
}
....
}
```

It is clear that `class MultipleChoice` can access the `question, type, and correctAnswer` in `class Question`. But when I try to access them in `class TrueFalse` by`this.a`. I got an error. 
`cannot be resolved or is not a field`.

Thus, is the protected attribute in a class is only accessible in its subclass, but not sub-subclass? Three files are in the same package but different class file.

Comment: Please clarify, because it works fine here (as stated).

Comment: Put up a complete [mcve] please.

Comment: Just for the record: you are sure multiple choice does not redeclare those fields?

Comment: @GhostCat I actually used them in MultipleChoice's constructor.

Comment: its basically the definition of protected, any subclass of a class that can access a protected property can itself access the property.

Comment: Again: put up an [mcve]. Something that we could try to compile run ourselves.

Comment: @GhostCat Oh, I didn't redeclare them in MultipleChoice class. Should I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I copy/pasted your code into an online compiler and tried it out. It worked, and you can find it [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMYVBUWWtiM1hjTkk). That looks like a yes.

I mean, if those were private fields it would make sense, but with the rest there shouldn't be a problem (unless it is package-access only).

Are you declaring those classes in the same file? If one of those is a nested class, that might be the cause.

### Reply to old version

> Super-super field access, uh? Hmm...
>
> How about `((A)this).a`? If the field is protected, maybe this could work.
>
> **NOTE:** If it still doesn't work for you, try using it inside a non-static method inside C.

Comment: @AllenYang where are you exactly writing the code to access field `a`?

Comment: @AllenYang I just copy/pasted into a generic online compiler and ran it without warnings.

Comment: it is wired. Actually I also used protected data in the constructor of MultipleChoice. Is  that a reason?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can. It's private methods that you can't access.

Comment: What do you mean onCreate  its normal java pc application and not android

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MultilevelVar {
public static void main(String[] args) {
new C().fun();
}
}

class A {
protected int x = 10;
}

class B extends A {
int x = 20;
}

class C extends B {
int x = 30;
void fun() {
System.out.println(((A) this).x);
System.out.println(((B) this).x);
System.out.println(((C) this).x);
}
}
```

Comment: You can use variable from _n_ level of hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, I'm declaring new x in each level.

Comment: And that is not the point. A protected field is visible from subclasses by default. Your example is shadowing the inherented protected field by creating another field withe the same name!